# Can Entity Framework create incremental SQL scripts for updates?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Can Entity Framework create incremental SQL scripts for updates?   (or would you need to do this in a separate database tool)

(i.e. for my application updates I need to package the DB upgrade script that gets applied after download - windows forms type app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't, but Visual Studio "Data Dude" can. [This plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87) unites the two.